# name clash have the same erasure

Tags: java, generics

I've searched other similar questions, but I don't think they cover this. I have the following code, which is causing a compile error:

```java
// Example 1 (not working)
public interface I<T extends Number> {
    void method(Map<String, String> map, T value);
}

public abstract class A<T extends Number> implements I<T> {
    @Override
    public void method(Map<String, String> map, T value) {}
}

// Note that C doesn't know about the generic type
public class C extends A {
    // Error: name clash: method(Map<String,String>,Number) in C and
    // method(Map,Number) in A have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other
    @Override
    public void method(Map<String, String> map, Number n) {}
}
```

I understand type erasure, but when I "manually" type erase, it works, so this code is fine.

```java
// Example 2 (working)
public interface I<T extends Number> {
    void method(Map map, T value);
}

public abstract class A<T extends Number> implements I<T> {
    @Override
    public void method(Map map, T value) {}
}

public class C extends A {
    // No error
    @Override
    public void method(Map map, Number n) {}
}
```

The generic T isn't the problem either, presumably, because it works if I remove the Map parameter so this is fine as well, (and anyways the error is complaining about the Map not the generic type so this isn't surprising):

```java
// Example 3 (working)
public interface I<T extends Number> {
    void method(T value);
}

public abstract class A<T extends Number> implements I<T> {
    @Override
    public void method(T value) {}
}

public class C extends A {
    // No error
    @Override
    public void method(Number n) {}
}
```

But removing the type parameter also fixes it, so the problem isn't the map either, I guess:

```java
// Example 4 (working)
public interface I {
    void method(Map<String, String> map);
}

public abstract class A implements I {
    @Override
    public void method(Map<String, String> map) {}
}

public class C extends A {
    @Override
    public void method(Map<String, String> map) {}
}
```

This is a small example, but this cropped up because I'm trying to add the generic type T to the interface without requiring changes to C, which is implemented in code I don't control, so changing I or A in an incompatible way with C isn't an option, but I would like to be able to use the generic in classes that do upgrade to use the generics. I would have thought this would work though, and that adding the generic with a constraint on it with the existing type would be a backwards compatible change, and in most places it is, as methods that follow the form in example 3 work fine.

Anyways, I'm not sure what the error is exactly here, since example 3 works, any theory about the general form being invalid seems to be incorrect, but since example 2 works, it also feels like this has nothing to do with type erasure, but perhaps some interesting interaction between generics AND type erasure that I'm not aware of.

Comment: I am missing `public class C extends A<Number> {
    @Override public void method(Map<String, String> map, Number n) {} }` -- from [JLS 4.8. Raw Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.8): "The use of raw types is allowed only as a concession to compatibility of legacy code. The use of raw types in code written after the introduction of generics into the Java programming language is strongly discouraged."

Comment: Yeah, trouble is that C represents subclasses that I don't control. I own the superclass, and can break compatibility, but that's a major change that I would like to avoid if at all possible. But if this isn't possible, I'll just not use generics for now. Still, strange that example 3 AND 4 should work, but not 1, and that the error is about the map, which doesn't use raw types, not the generics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't ideal, but you could resolve the issue in the first example by splitting A into two, leaving `A` without generic definitions, and adding a new supertype which deals with the generic:

```
// Rename A as SuperA
public class SuperA<T extends Number> implements I<T> {
    @Override
    public void method(Map<String, String> map, T value) {}
}
// Insert new A which hasn't got the generic A<T> but declares T as Number for C
public class A extends ASuper<Number> {
    @Override
    public void method(Map<String, String> map, Number value) {}
}
```

This has the effect of providing the right type `Number` for the class `C` which you say that you cannot change.

Obviously, this might have some impact on your other code which may use `A`, as `A` doesn't have quite the same definition as before.

Comment: Interesting idea! This should work, I can make a hard change eventually, but there just needs to be a deprecation period. It shouldn't be a problem to maintain both of these classes for some period of time to allow third parties to all update. I'll still hold out hope that there is another better solution, but this is good enough for me in the meantime.